# Reading excel data starting from a specific row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read an excel data set starting from a specific row in a workbook containing multiple sheets. I can't use the row index as the location of the row I want to start with changes in each sheet.

My data looks like this:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| start after this | A |
| 07:00 | B |
| 08:00 | C |
| 09:00 | D |

and I wanted to read the data starting from whatever row is before 08:00

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 07:00 | B |
| 08:00 | C |
| 09:00 | D |

I have tried the following but I am getting an error that it can't find "08:00" in the list

```
df = df[df.index[list(df.index.values).index('08:00') - 1:]]
```

I would appreciate any hints, many thanks in advance!

Comment: I would actually write the iteration out explicitly here: iterate by row until you find the index you want, save the index, and then use the value later.  That way it's obvious what you're doing

Comment: What is returned if no match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values of `index` converted to `Series`, so possible add [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for previous match and [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html) for next `True`s:

```
print (df)
                 Another header
A header                       
start after this              A
07:00                         B
08:00                         C
09:00                         D
```

---

```
print (df[(df.index.to_series() == '08:00').shift(-1,fill_value=False).cummax()])
         Another header
A header               
07:00                 B
08:00                 C
09:00                 D

print (df[(df.index.to_series() == '07:00').shift(-1,fill_value=False).cummax()])
                 Another header
A header                       
start after this              A
07:00                         B
08:00                         C
09:00                         D

print (df[(df.index.to_series() == '09:00').shift(-1,fill_value=False).cummax()])
         Another header
A header               
08:00                 C
09:00                 D

print (df[(df.index.to_series() == '17:00').shift(-1,fill_value=False).cummax()])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Another header]
Index: []
```

Comment: That should work but I pandas ad automatically an index row to my data. therefore, I need to make the script reads from col[1] instead of col[0] as col[0] is the automaticity generated index col. Would that change the solution dramatically?

Comment: @Kimchi - If need select first column change `df.index.to_series()` to `df.iloc[:, 0]`  or `df.iloc[:, 1]` if need select second column

Answer (score 0):

I would write the iteration out explicitly to make things clear:

```py
start = 0 # in case we fail to find it later
for i, row in df["Col 1 header"].iteritems():
    if "07:00" in row:
        start = i -1
        break
```

Then you can just use `start` from then on.